# Radon complex measure + $\mu(G) = ||\mu ||$ implies $\mu \geq 0$

Tags: measure-theory, fourier-analysis

I'm reading *Fourier Analysis in groups* by Walter Rudin, and *A Course on Abstract Harmonic Analysis* by Folland. In particular, I'm reading the Bochner Theorem's proof. However, my question doesn't need about that. First, some considerations.

- Let $G$ be a locally compact (Hausdorff) group.
- $M(G)$ is the Banach Algebra of complex Radon Measures on $G$, with the norm $||\mu||$ (the total variation, I can include the definition here if you need it).

In the final part of Bochner Theorem's proof, it says something like (not exactly, I want to simplify in order to be understood):

($\mu \in M(G)$) Since $\mu(G) = ||\mu||$, then $\mu \geq 0$.

Why?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the proof p. 21 from Rudin's book, we have a complex-valued Radon measure $\mu$ on $G$ such that $\mu(G) = 1 = \| \mu \| := |\mu|(G)$. We prove that this implies $\mu \geq 0$.
Consider $\phi \in C^0(G, \Bbb R_{ \geq 0})$. We have

\begin{align*}
 \| \varphi \|_{\infty} - \mathrm{Im}\left( \int_{G} \varphi\,d\mu \right) &\stackrel{\mu(G) = 1}{=} 
 \text{Im}\left( \int_{G} [\| \varphi \|_{\infty} \mathbb 1_{G} -  \varphi]\,d\mu  \right) 
 \leq \Big\| \| \varphi\|_{\infty} \mathbb 1_{G}  -   \varphi \Big\|_{\infty} \|\mu\| 
 \stackrel{\phi \geq 0}{\leq} \| \varphi \|_{\infty}
\end{align*}

Thus
$$\mathrm{Im}\left( \int_{G} \varphi\,d\mu \right) \geq 0$$
and hence $\mathrm{Im}(\mu(E)) \geq 0$ for any Borel set $E \subset G$. Moreover, $\mathrm{Im}(\mu(G)) = 0$, which implies that $\mu$ is real-valued. Using the same argument as above, one shows that $\mathrm{Re}(\mu(E)) \geq 0$ for any Borel set $E \subset G$. Therefore, $\mu$ is a positive measure.

Comment: Your have a similar result if you consider "measures" as elements $m \in \ell^{\infty}(X)^*$ (for any set $X$) : consider the statements a) $m(f) \geq 0$ for all $f \geq 0$, b) $m(\mathbb 1_X) = 1$, and c) $\|m\|=1$. Then any two of these assertions imply the third.

Comment: Thank you very much. I need to reference it for a project, do you know if I could find it in any book? I prefer your first answer.

Comment: One more thing, have you used Urysohn Lemma?

Comment: @Glazunov : 1) Unfortunately, I did not find any explicit reference which proves this ; you would have to include it by yourself. 2) Urysohn's lemma is not used, but I used a density result of $C^0(G) \cap L^1(G)$ in $L^1(G)$ (to go from continuous $\phi : G \to \Bbb R_{\geq 0}$ to any Borel $E \subset G$), see Prop. 7.4.3. in Cohn's _Measure Theory_.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll see it tomorrow.